# Yii2: db access from widget

Tags: yii2

Widgets should be designed to be self-contained and they should not access a database directly. But recently I've come across the code that uses a direct access to the database to retrieve widget settings, and also caches retrieved values.
Here's the part of the widget:

```
class DbCarousel extends Carousel
{
    // ...
    public function init()
    {
        $cacheKey = [
            WidgetCarousel::className(),
            $this->key
        ];
        $items = Yii::$app->cache->get($cacheKey);
        if ($items === false) {
            $items = [];
            $query = WidgetCarouselItem::find()
                ->joinWith('carousel')
                ->where([
                    '{{%widget_carousel_item}}.status' => 1,
                    '{{%widget_carousel}}.status' => WidgetCarousel::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                    '{{%widget_carousel}}.key' => $this->key,
                ])
                ->orderBy(['order' => SORT_ASC]);
            foreach ($query->all() as $k => $item) {
                /** @var $item \common\models\WidgetCarouselItem */
                if ($item->path) {
                    $items[$k]['content'] = Html::img($item->getImageUrl());
                }
                if ($item->caption) {
                    $items[$k]['caption'] = $item->caption;
                }
            }
            Yii::$app->cache->set($cacheKey, $items, 60*60*24*365);
        }
        $this->items = $items;
        parent::init();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Question is: can widget under any circumstances access a database, or it's a sign that refactoring is needed?

Comment: widgets are self-contained but you should probably change the approach you should provide the data to the widget while initializing if the items you need the carousel to work with is from database rather than adding the query inside the carousel widget , just like a dropdown widget than can show any items either static or dynamic by passing the set of options in form of `name=>value` pairs, declare a public property `$data` and initialize it via options like 
`DbCarousel::widget('data'=>$yourDataSet)`

Comment: but officially on the docs there isnt anything written like **it should not access database** at least i can find it.although it does make sense.

Comment: I think so too. I read some articles that suggested not to access a database from widgets and it makes sense, cause allowing so makes database requests smeared all over the application. But I often find examples of widgets with db access code, so I wonder if there are any cons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically querying data and representing it are two different tasks, so such widget breaks single responsibility principle. However Yii has already a abstraction for retrieving data from database (`ActiveRecord` and/or `ActiveQuery`), so it is not that simple. You don't need to create separate data provider class for calling `News::find()->newestFirst()->limit(5)->all()` - usually it is easier and more pragmatic to call this query directly in `LatestNewsWidget`.

In general you have three situations with widgets:

1. Widget may display different sets of data in the same way (like `GridView`).
2. The same data may be displayed in different ways by different widgets, like widget for displaying menu - there is one menu stored in database, but depending on layout different widget should be used.
3. Both, way of displaying and data, is unique - for example you have only one menu and only one layout (so there is only one widget for displaying menu).

As far as two first cases clearly indicates that data source and widget should be separated, it is not that clear in third case. Personally I'm often using widgets which are responsible for retrieving all necessary data and dependencies, so I can use them simply by `MyWidget::widget()`. I never had any problems with this, but I'm trying to avoid too complicated DB queries - complicity usually should be hidden behind `ActiveQuery` abstraction. Also you always need to be prepared for refactoring and extracting querying data to separate component - at some point your unique widget with unique set of data may become not unique and separating widget and data provider may be the only sane way to keep your code DRY.

Comment: Thank you for an exhaustive answer, you've clarified my doubts!